# Why can a local taylor expansion tell how many derivatives are continuous?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Define $\chi=x(1+\cos(x))$ for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ and extend $\chi$ periodically to the entire real line. I want to check the continuity of $\chi'$ and $\chi''$ at $\pi$. A solution was shown as the following:

Since $\chi(\pi-\varepsilon)=(\pi-\varepsilon)(1-\cos(\varepsilon))$, we get
$$\chi(\pi-\varepsilon)=\frac{\pi}{2}\varepsilon^2-\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^3+\cdots$$
showing that the first derivative is continuous but the second is not.

I am pretty confused by this statement. I tried to link the local expansion to the expansion of $\chi$ about $\pi$ to deduce that $\chi''$ is not continuous at $\pi$. But I couldn't get any further.
$$\chi(\pi-\varepsilon)=\chi(\pi)+\chi'(\pi)(-\varepsilon)+\chi''(\pi)(-\varepsilon)^2+\cdots$$
if we suppose $\chi''(\pi)$ exists. How does this tells us $\chi''$ is not continuous?

Comment: But $\chi''$ is continuous. In fact, $\chi$ is analytic.

Comment: @martini Sorry. I have edited the question. I forgot a very important condition.

Answer (score 0):

Take

$$f(x)=x^3\sin(\frac 1x) \;if\; x\ne 0$$
and $ f(0)=0$.

$ f(x) $ can be seen as

$$f(x)=0+0.x+0.x^2+x^2(x\sin(\frac 1x))$$
$$=0+0.x+0.x^2+x^2\epsilon(x)$$

this says that $ f(x) $ has a second order Taylor expansion arround $ x=0 $

but, you can check that $ f''(0) $ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have revised my question so it's a new one now. I apologize for forgetting an important condition.